# How to get the data grater than/less than the provided date in linux

Tags: linux, unix

I have sample.txt file where the data in the file looks like the following :

```
LINE 1|2017-02-19|LINE 3|LINE 4| LINE 5 | LINE 6
LINE 1|2017-02-06|LINE 3|LINE 4| LINE 5 | LINE 6
LINE 1|2017-03-06|LINE 3|LINE 4| LINE 5 | LINE 6
LINE 1|2017-02-07|LINE 3|LINE 4| LINE 5 | LINE 6
LINE 1|2017-03-25|LINE 3|LINE 4| LINE 5 | LINE 6
LINE 1|2017-02-06|LINE 3|LINE 4| LINE 5 | LINE 6
```

Now I want to get the data from the sample.txt file where

```
2017-02-19
2017-02-06
2017-03-06
2017-02-07    
2017-03-25
2017-02-06

            > 2017-02-19
```

So my output should be look like

```
LINE 1|2017-03-06|LINE 3|LINE 4| LINE 5 | LINE 6
LINE 1|2017-03-25|LINE 3|LINE 4| LINE 5 | LINE 6
```

Comment: Maybe something like `awk '$0 > "LINE 1|2017-02-20"' sample.txt`

Answer (score 1):

## Using GNU [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) and [date](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html#date-invocation)

- Set [field separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Input-Summary.html) `FS` to `|`
- `date -d[DATE] +[OUTPUT_FORMAT]…` will format field two (`$2`) as number of seconds since the *[unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch)* (`%s`) and pipe it to the variable `d`
- Awk will test that `d` is less than `2017-02-19` whose number of seconds since the epoch is `1487480400` and **if true** will print the whole record `$0`

### Code

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";} { "date -d"$2" +%s" | getline d;} d < 1487480400 { print $0; }'
```

*Note: you can print only certain fields by changing `print $0;` to something like `print $1;`, `print $1,$2;`, or even `print $1"anythingYouWantHereQuoted"$2;`*

#### Finding number of seconds since the Unix epoch given date

You can find the number of seconds since the Unix epoch given a date using `date -d2017-02-19 +%s` from the command line, for example.

Answer (score 0):

read the file line by line,
isolate the date,
compare the date (formatted as a number), 
skip the line, or print the line

```
#!/bin/ksh

compareDay=$( date -d '2017-02-19' "+%Y%j" )    # build a number from <year><day of year>
cat sample.txt | while read line; do
    day="${line#*\|}"           # remove from the beginning to first |
    day="${day%%\|*}"           # remove from the end (%%=all) up from |
    # compare, skip if condition not met
    [[ $( date -d $day "+%Y%j" ) -gt $compareDay ]] || continue
    echo "$line"                # output the remaining line meeting the condition
done
```

This assumes you may have to deal with input that has different values in the first column. Otherwise @bren's solution is sufficent.

Which in ksh would be

```
cat sample.txt | while read line; do
    [[ $line > 'LINE 1|2017-02-20' ]] || continue
    echo "$line"
done
```